# How to convert DECLARE_HANDLE and subsequent consts from windef.h to Delphi

Tags: delphi, winapi

The following code is from the Windows 10 Anniversary Update SDK. I need the constant handles in order to use the API in Delphi because as of today, these headers are not included in Delphi.

```
  DECLARE_HANDLE(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT);

  #define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE           ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-1)
  #define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE      ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-2)
  #define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-3)
```

When I use [GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748626(v=vs.85).aspx) in various DPI scenarios, I have learned what the values as NativeUInts are:

```
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = 16;  
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = 17;
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = 18;
```

But I would like to be 100% certain that these values are future-proof. They do work in [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748629(v=vs.85).aspx) calls and have the desired effect, but I am unclear on how these values are arrived at.  I could not duplicate a header construct in Delphi that produced those results, aside for the explicit integer declaration.

Comment: As stated below, these "magic numbers" are the returned values from GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext in each of those conditions -- and they also work with SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext and achieve the expected/desired results.

Comment: I don't quite understand the declaration here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt791579(v=vs.85).aspx. As what is what declared? Is this an enum, a struct, an array, what? I mean something like  `typedef HANDLE xxx { aaa, bbb, ccc } Txxx;`. What kind of a declaration is that?

Comment: @Rudy that's why I dug around in the SDK for actual declaration. I ended up missing the obvious -- basically each of those constants is just a negative integer cast to a handle.

Comment: indeed. In C and C++, handles are pointers, so they simply declared these magic numbers as handles, as that is what you usually pass around between such API calls. It is funny how you get values like 16 or 18 when the magic numbers are -1, etc.

Comment: My problem was in reading ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-1) as arithmetic instead of a cast. The syntax threw me.

Comment: It bit me at first too. Took a few minutes before I recognized them as cast. I also though: some number minus one, minus two  and minus three. <g>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For use in  [SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748629(v=vs.85).aspx) you should declare it as

```
type
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = type THandle;
const
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE          = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-1);
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE     = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-2);
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE= DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-3);
```

but when you get response from [GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748626(v=vs.85).aspx) you need to use [GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748622(v=vs.85).aspx) on received value and compare it with  [DPI_AWARENESS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt748620(v=vs.85).aspx) enum.

You cannot directly compare `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` since it contains multiple pieces of information and Microsoft may change it in the future.

Comment: Anyway this is the right answer. Thanks. For whatever reason, I completely missed the obvious typecasting.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs These are just _magic_ numbers for setting data, when you are getting value it contains current and inherited values for DPI awareness, maybe they will add something more there. Using extra function to get awareness protects you from breaking code in the future.

Comment: Note that `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = type THandle` does not give any more type safety than `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = THandle`. All integer types are assignment compatible. If you want type safety then you would need to wrap the handle in a record. Or use pointer to record.

Comment: Documentation topic that covers type compatibility: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity

Answer (score 7):

Delphi does not use C/C++ include files at all, so it doesn't matter if the Windows SDK is shipped with the IDE or not, it won't be used in Delphi projects.  Now, if you are worried about Delphi not providing *Pascal translations* of the C header files, that is another story.

`DECLARE_HANDLE()` is a C preprocessor macro that declares a new data type alias based on the value of the input parameter and whether or not the preprocessor `STRICT` conditional is defined:

```
#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
#else
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif
```

`STRICT` provides more type-safety to C/C++ code.  Many Win32 handle types are opaque types in user code.  Declaring them using `DECLARE_HANDLE()` allows the compiler to treat them as distinct data types when `STRICT` is defined, thus prevents different handle types from being mixed together erroneously (ie, passing an `HBITMAP` where an `HWND` is expected, etc).  A lot of developers made that kind of mistake before `STRICT` was introduced, since all handle types were effectively `void*`, preventing any compile-time validations.

This means that `DECLARE_HANDLE(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)` will declare `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` like this:

1. when `STRICT` is defined:

   ```
   struct DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__{int unused;};
   typedef struct DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__ *DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT;
   ```
2. when `STRICT` is not defined:

   ```
   typedef void* DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT;
   ```

So, `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` is declared as either a **pointer to a record type** or as an **untyped pointer**, depending on `STRICT`.

That kind of name resolution cannot be translated to Delphi, since it does not support preprocessor macros like C/C++ does.  The closest translation would be to declare `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` directly instead:

```
type
  {$IFDEF STRICT}
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__ = record
  end; 
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = ^DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__;
  {$ELSE}
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = Pointer;
  {$ENDIF}
```

Or simply forget the existence of `STRICT` altogether in Delphi:

```
type
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__ = record
  end; 
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = ^DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__;
```

Either way, once `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` is declared, you can then declare its constant values:

```
const
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-1);
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-2);
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-3);
```

---

**Update**: based on comments, you can alternatively use this instead:

```
type
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT = type THandle;

const
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-1);  
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-2);
  DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE = DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT(-3);
```

Note that these constants are only used for input to `SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()`, NOT for output from `GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()`.  The latter returns an opaque handle to a private memory structure.  You need to use `GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext()` to retrieve the actual `DPI_AWARENESS` value from that structure.

Comment: Note that the `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT__` you define is an opaque type, and it is absolutely not interesting what the struct it points to is. Just declare it as Pointer or even better, THandle (an integral type), and all is well. These are, as far as the user is concerned, magic numbers, no more.

Comment: Of course Delphi can't use the C headers.  That's why I need the conversion.  I am already using GetProcAddress to load the function pointers.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: it is *supposed* to be an opaque record type. That is what `STRICT` does in C/C++. If you declare it as just an alias for `THandle` or even `Pointer`, you lose all type safety (you can pass *any* `THandle` value where `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT` is expected). By declaring it as a pointer to a record type (even an empty one), type safety is maintained.

Comment: I got the "magic numbers" by querying GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext. If the program is multi-monitor DPI aware, this returns a handle with a value of 18.  If it is not aware of DPI at all, it gets 16.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs: then it is returning illegal values, since those values are not in the documentation or the SDK declarations. Are you sure you are not misinterpreting what you are receiving??

Comment: Type safety may be maintained, but you will see it is not compatible with any future conversions done by Embarcadero. Handles are declared as, well, THandle. If they (well, Borland) had used empty records and pointers to those from the beginning, all would be well. But since handles often were magical numbers and not real pointers at all, especially in early Windows, declaring them as integral types made sense. And well, see Eugene's solution: `xxx = type THandle`. The best of both worlds.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs: I did a test on Win10, and `GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext()` in a non DPI-aware process returns 18 for me, not 16.

Comment: The values returned by GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext are not meant to match the defined consts for SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext. That's part of what was confusing me.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `HANDLE`s sometimes are pointers, just not in an address space that a user space program can use. If they had been declared as pointer types then they would have had the desirable property that their size was the same as a pointer. As far as *`xxx = type THandle`, the best of both worlds*, not so much. It would be nice if what you said was true. It is not. Integer types are assignment compatible. There's no type safety gained with `xxx = type THandle` over `xxx = THandle`. If you want type safety you need to wrap in a record. Or use pointer to record.

Comment: Documentation topic that covers type compatibility: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity

Comment: OK, you are right, they are still assignment compatible. But declaring a handle as pointer is, in Delphi, at the current time, not a good idea. It should have been done at early Borland times (at the time of D2). Now it is far too late to change that. In Delphi, handles have always been treated as integral types. Making them pointers (or making *some of them* pointers) would cause confusion. And if, as done here (by MS) If you cast the "pointerness" on integral values anyway, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis If you want type safety then declaring them as pointers is one of only two options that I can see. The other being a record containing a pointer sized integer. But that latter approach is inconvenient with magic values as per this question. So, if type safety is a desirable goal, as you yourself have stated, then pointers as outlined by Remy is the only option. Your criticism of the casting isn't very apposite. The beneficiary of the type safety of `STRICT` is the consumer of the library, and their benefits are not affected by the dirty work behind the scenes.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Anyway, my main point here was to raise awareness of an issue that a lot of people seem unaware of. Which I think I've done now.